# How can I post stories to current logged in user's Facebook wall using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook-opengraph, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-stream-story

I am using Facebook C# SDK to login to my website. Login works correctly but what I want is to post my app's open graph actions to logged in user's timeline. I used this code but it only posts textual status on users wall. Please tell me how should I post some specific actions

```
FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp();
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(fbApp.Session.AccessToken);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["message"] = "abc";
args["caption"] = "This is caption!";
args["description"] = "This is description!";
args["name"] = "This is name!";
args["picture"] = "[your image URL]";
args["link"] = "[your link URL]";

app.Api("/me/feed", args, HttpMethod.Post);
```

An example of what I want is
http://www.wrangle.in/login.aspx

Comment: What is in the docs / samples? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the above code. And I searched on http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/ but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used this code but it only posts textual status on users wall.

Of course, because you are posting to `/me/feed`.

How to published actions, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#create

Edit:
To do so from within your C# project, just make the API call with the method you are using right now – but to the right endpoint, and with the right parameters.

Comment: ya I already read it but is there any way of doing it using C# SDK??

Comment: Just make the API call with the method you are using right now – but to the right endpoint, and with the right parameters.

Comment: Ok I will try and tell you then. Modify your answer and I will mark it.